# Generate two same random alpha-numeric strings in different java programs

Tags: java, security, random

I am looking to see if there is a possibility to generate two same alpha-numeric strings in two different java codes. This is for the purpose of secured communication between client and server.

Or is there an alternative way to do this?

I looked at the usual ways of public private key encryption and related stuff. For my requirement, I do not need such a mechanism as its kind of too much of standard stuff. I am kind of looking for a simple alternative like this.

Thanks,
Abishek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is akin to a [time-synchronized one-time password](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_password#Time-synchronized).

A simplistic way to do this is to use the system time, rounded to the nearest, say, 6-second 'pulse' as a seed for a cryptographically secure random number generator (Java provides `SecureRandom` FWIW). Then, along with a pre-shared 'secret' put that through a one-way cryptographic hash (say, SHA256) to generate your alpha-numeric (hex or base64) string.

If you don't need to display/pass along the actual string, then I suppose you can skip the hash step and just use the shared secret and the synchronized time as the IV + key for a cipher applied to the communications stream on both ends.

The obvious risk or complication with this approach is keeping the two system clocks in sync. If you use NTP or some other time synchronization protocol, then you have to secure that as well (otherwise you're potentially open to a replay attack). Standard computer clocks are prone to drift (hence the 6-second window) and you have to secure them from tampering as well.

(Disclaimer: I am *not* a security specialist so don't think for a moment that what I've outlined about is completely secure/safe as is.)

Comment: Just realized that even just the system time and the 'secret' should be enough to generate a reasonably secure cryptographic hash (no need for the random number generation). Also, another possible risk is if the 'secret' becomes known, the system time (rounded) can be guessed relatively easily, allowing an eavesdropper to break the Cipher. Didn't want to edit my original answer after acceptance, though.

Answer (score 0):

If two different systems are generating the same string then the generator will usually not be cryptographically secure.  Once the attacker knows the inputs she will be able to generate the same string, and the inputs will be things like the current date/time as Alistair suggests.

This is not a new problem, and it has already been solved.  Peter has pointed you at [Diffie-Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange), which is the standard secure solution for establishing a shared secret (i.e. the key) over an insecure line.